# Polymer 1.x: Is google-chart temporarily down via polygit?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polygit

[In this jsBin, I am trying to display a `google-chart` element](http://jsbin.com/dusaqaqaje/edit?html,console,output) by copypasting [the first example from the docs page here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart). But the chart does not display.

Can anyone confirm or reject my hypothesis that the reason the bin is not working is because of a similar *temporary* **server** issue at [polygit2.appspot.com](https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/) ([similar to this case of two days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35642892/1640892))? Or is there something wrong with the code that needs fixing?

http://jsbin.com/dusaqaqaje/edit?html,console,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!---- >
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <!---- >
  Toggle below/above as backup when server is down
  <!---->
  <base href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/">
  <!---->
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
  <link href="google-chart/google-chart.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style></style>

<paper-button on-tap="_handleTap">Click Me</paper-button>

<!---- >
  Below is just a copypaste from the docs page here:
  https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart
<!---->
<google-chart
  type='pie'
  options='{"title": "Distribution of days in 2001Q1"}'
  cols='[{"label":"Month", "type":"string"}, {"label":"Days", "type":"number"}]'
  rows='[["Jan", 31],["Feb", 28],["Mar", 31]]'>
</google-chart>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {
      },
      _handleTap: function() {
        console.log('You clicked me!');
      },
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a temporary server issue, as you already proposed. Importing this `google-chart` element via polygit just throws an error instead of serving the element ([you may see this behaviour in your import link](https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/google-chart/google-chart.html)).

Hopefully this will be fixed soon.